# Is there any way to make schedule a service in a Spring API without using the Scheduler annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule my service, but I don't want to use de Scheduler, because I already have too many asynchronous on my API. Anyone knows a solution? My doubt is how to do it without use a entire thread to do it.

Comment: what does 'asynchronous' have to do with your scheduler process. It's going to be a separate backend process that will be running on the backend

Comment: You could use an external scheduler like cron

Comment: You'd need a separate thread to handle the scheduled process anyway. If you don't, other processes might slow down, delay or even block the scheduled execution of the service. Fortunately the JVM is good at handling many threads even on few cores.

Comment: Also: "I already have too many asynchronous on my API" - do you realize that some frameworks like Vert.x etc. are basically doing _everything_ asynchronously? Asynchronous processing has its challenges but also advantages and thus I wouldn't dismiss a solution just because it's asynchronous, especially if it's as simple as using a scheduler.